# Python get-pip install failes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am attempting to install PIP into my Python so I can install other modules.  But I am getting the errors below.  Any ideas?

[root@sandbox ~]# python3 get-pip.py
Collecting pip<18
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),)': /packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),)': /packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),)': /packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),)': /packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),)': /packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),))

Comment: have you tried with `--trusted-host`? i.e. `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org get-pip.py`

Comment: @rv.kvetch He does not have pip yet, still using `get-pip.py`.

Comment: Can you import `ssl` and check `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`?

Comment: [root@sandbox ~]# python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all issue turned out to be back end HTTPS restrictions on our network.
I had to get a bypass to install PIP itself.  Once that was done I was able to install modules using the trusted host method.